# Почему элементы таблицы отображаются по разному?

Tags: css

Не пойму почему элементы таблицы отображаются по разному, а именно, то по 4 элемента в строке, то по 1?.
http://vashe-rukodelie.ru/catalog/sets-for-embroidery/km-2/make-your-own-hands/

Если присвоить display:table; то выводится все нормально,но по 3 столбца.
Я пытаюсь добиться того,что бы разбиение на столбцы было автоматическим,в зависимости от монитора.

Comment: Елена:
Проблема в том,что у меня в  Html записано так:
<div class="content">
           <?php
      Core_Page::instance()->execute();
           ?>  
</div>
Т.е. таблица выводится сама,настраивать я ее могу только через css.

Comment: Печаль. Не понимаю ничего в php. Про него рассказывают ужасы, но не верю: должна быть и в нём возможность исправить шаблон подключаемого блока. Но даже если вдруг все страшилки-пугалки правда, всё равно можно справиться исключительно средствами css: каждому n-ному элементу создать псевдоэлемент, очищающий поток, а саму обёртку элемента вывести из потока. Оформление же назначить вложенному блоку. Вложенность у вас с запасом.

Comment: если не трудно,то подскажите как это сделать.
вот кусок из css,который отвечает за вывод товаров в таблице:
.shop_table {

    display: block;

    margin-bottom: 30px;

    width: 100%;
}



.shop_table .shop_item {

    display: table-cell;

    float: left;

    margin: 20px 5px;

    text-align: center;

    vertical-align: top;

    width: 220px;

}




.shop_table_item {

    display: table;

    height: 100%;

    width: 100%;

}

Comment: будет нетрудно, если будет рабочий образец на jsfiddle. Обещаю.

Answer (score 1):

для этого совершенно не обязательно представлять элементы как табличные. Посмотрите, как такое принято решать при использовании бутстрапа: для каждого диапазона разрешений своя ширина элементов, а между ними блоки clearfix, видимые только при своих разрешениях. Вы можете сделать так же.